# Proof of elementary result concerning Equinumerous sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

NOTE: THE NOTATION $A\thicksim B$ implies that $A$ is equinumerous to $B$.

Is the following Proof Correct?

**Theorem.** For all integers $m$ and $n$ if $I_n\thicksim I_m$ then $n=m$, where $I_n$ and $I_m$ are defined such that $I_n = \{i\in\mathbf{Z^+}|i\leq n\}$ and $I_m = \{j\in\mathbf{Z^+}|j\leq m\}$.

**Proof.** For purpose of clarity let us first state the above statement as follows.
$$\forall n\in\mathbf{N}\forall m\in\mathbf{N}(I_n\thicksim I_m \implies m=n)$$
We construct the proof by recourse to *Mathematical-induction* on $n$.

For the *Basis-Step* i.e. $n = 0$ we proceed by letting $m$ be an arbitrary natural number and then assuming for purpose of contradiction that $I_0 \thicksim I_m$ and $m\neq 0$, which implies that $m\in\mathbf{Z^+}$ and the existence of a *bijection* $f:I_0\to I_m$.

Consequently $\forall x\in I_m\exists y\in I_0(x = f(y))$, in particular for $x=1$ but $I_0 = \varnothing$ so no such $y$ exists resulting in a contradiction.

For the *Inductive-Step* let us first assume for an arbitrary $k\in\mathbf{N}$ that
$$\forall q\in\mathbf{N}(I_k\thicksim I_q \implies k = q)$$
and assume further for an arbitrary $m\in\mathbf{N}$ that $I_{k+1}\thicksim I_m$, from this we may invoke the existence of a *bijection* $g:I_{k+1}\to I_m$, consequently the function $g|_{I_k}:I_k\to I_m\backslash\{g(k+1)\}$ is also a *bijection* from $I_k$ to $I_m\backslash\{g(k+1)\}$ which implies that $I_k\thicksim I_m\backslash\{g(k+1)\}$ evidently $I_m\backslash\{g(k+1)\thicksim I_{m-1}$ and thus by transitivity $I_k\thicksim I_{m-1}$ this together with the use of the inductive hypothesis implies that $k = m-1$ and thus $k+1 =m$.

$\blacksquare$

Comment: Considering how careful you’re being with the rest of the proof, you should probably note that $I_{k+1}=I_k\cup\{k+1\}$. And I think you’re being inconsistent on level-of-detail when you say “evidently $I_m\backslash\{g(k+1)\}\sim I_{m-1}$” and should exhibit the bijection. Otherwise the proof is fine. Another point about style is that one normally doesn’t bother explicitly stating base step/induction hypothesis/induction step. Say you will prove by induction, then just write the proof for $n=0$, then write “suppose true for $k$” or something to hat effect, and prove for $k+1$.

Comment: One normally only writes “by the induction hypothesis” if it isn’t obvious how it is applied.